# Accessing variables from within a module

Tags: ruby, oop

Trying to get a variable defined outside a module from within a module

```
@variable = "variable"

module A
  def write
    puts @variable
  end
end

extend A
write # -> "variable"
# works ok, but i'll be loading a few modules with the same method name "write"
# need to be able to call A.write, A1.write, A2.write and so on

module B
  module_function
  def write
    puts @variable
  end
end

extend B
B.write # ->  
# Can call the B.write
# is returning nothing, not getting @variable

module C
  module_function
  def write var
    puts var
  end
end

extend C
C.write @variable # -> "variable"
# works ok
```

is the solution i found good in practice? or is there a better way of doing it? not sure about calling module_function because i still don't get it after reading the definitions, not sure what else is it doing

Comment: This doesn't sound very wise to me. Please explain the problem you'e trying to solve with this approach. What is wrong with `A.write(@variable)` etc.?

Comment: What the reason to define variable outside the module? You can try `@@variable` It can be accessed by regular methods (In that respect, they are more similar to Java`s static fields)

Comment: i'm trying to make a ruby executable that scaffolds up my dev environment, purely for study. in short, i want to make ruby modules like "Bower.rb", "Grunt.rb" with the write method which contains the settings i prefer for that particular utility. `A.write @variable` returns an error because its not expecting an argument

Comment: @hawk i'd like to setup a project name var `@project_name` and have my module set up my utilities with reference to the project name correctly set up.I remember the ruby style guide repo on github telling me to stay away from `@@` vars, because of its inheritance behaviour, but ill try it.

Comment: @hawk its giving me an unitialized class variable error. I'm guessing its because of the module function statement?

Comment: @GeorgeAnandaEman most probably the things you are talking about are called global variables.